# Copy out a child Object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm trying to copy out a child Object into a variable, but it seems that by simply declaring it, only the key get's copied. How do I copy out the entire Object? Here's what I'm trying...

```
const baseObj = {
  players: {
    player1: {
      name: "hello",
      details: "something"
    },
    player2: ...
  }
}

const player1Copy = baseObj.players.player1
// I want to grab out the whole object player1 instead of just the key
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use **[`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)**

**DEMO**

```js
const baseObj = {
  players: {
    player1: {
      name: "hello",
      details: "something"
    } 
  }
}

let cloned = Object.assign({}, baseObj.players.player1); 

console.log(cloned);
```

Comment: alternative for modern JS `let cloned = {...baseObj.players.player1}; `